# Magento - Sort category view on date updated

Tags: magento

I'm trying to set the sort order in the category view for magento.

In */app/design/frontend/template_name/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml* the product category is called this way:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Is there a possibility to sort this collection using e.g. the following? For the record, this doesn't work. ;)

```
->addAttributeToSort('updated_at','asc')->setOrder('updated_at', 'asc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was doing some SQL queries.

Set a frontend label for the sort-by attribute.

```
update eav_attribute set frontend_label = "Updated" where attribute_code = "updated_at"
```

Enable used_for_sort_by

```
update catalog_eav_attribute set used_for_sort_by = 1 where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = "updated_at")
```

Set updated_at as standard sorting value (could also be done in back-end)

```
update core_config_data set value = "updated_at" where path = "catalog/frontend/default_sort_by"
```